# Tablayout's text color does not change when setting the selected item in code

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am trying to have the tabLayout change it's selected tab.

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.configuration_sheet_pager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.configuration_sheet_tabs);
    view.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(selectedColor);
    view.setTabTextColors(normallColor, selectedColor);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

To select a tab:

```
//Does not work; indicator moves but text color is not affected
viewPager.setCurrentItem(change.value, change.animated);
//works as expected
tabLayout.setScrollPosition(change.value,0f,true);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(change.value);
```

I am using Android Design support library 23.1.1. Have I found a bug?

Answer (score 1):

If you want `TabLayout` color change when you selected your tabLayout xml should be something like this:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#f32"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"/>
```

And call

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

**Or** do following:

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                tabLayout.getTabAt(position).select();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in Material TabLayout:

app:tabTextColor="@color/normal_color"

app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/selected_color"

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTabText"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/text_color"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/text_color"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

And For custom TabLayout add this in getView() method:

```
tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.drawable.selector_textview));
```

Add this in your drawable selector_textview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/selected_color" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/selected_color" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/selected_color" />
    <item android:color="@color/normal_color" />

</selector>
```